# Strange effect of C# closures on garbage collector

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

Straight to the code

```
class Program
{
    private static WeakReference<EventHandler<EventArgs>> _noClosure;
    private static WeakReference<EventHandler<EventArgs>> _closure;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Init();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        EventHandler<EventArgs> target;
        Console.WriteLine(_closure.TryGetTarget(out target));
        Console.WriteLine(_noClosure.TryGetTarget(out target));
    }

    class C { public void Go() { } }

    private static void Init()
    {
        _noClosure = new WeakReference<EventHandler<EventArgs>>((sender, args) =>
        {
        });

        var s = new C();
        _closure = new WeakReference<EventHandler<EventArgs>>((sender, args) =>
        {
              s.Go();
        });
    }
}
```

The output I get from this code is

```
False
True
```

How on earth is this possible?

P.S. I came into this while trying to figure out how `WeakEventManager` works.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler will cache the `_noClosure` delegate in a static field, and reuse it every time you call `Init`. The exact same instance can be reused every time.

Compare that with `_closure`, which closes over a new instance of `C()` on each call to `Init()` - that can't be cached.

The caching of `_noClosure` means that there's a strong reference (the field) to the delegate, so it can't be garbage collected.

If you run `ildasm` on your application, you can see all of this in action.

Comment: Is this an implementation detail, or that behavior is stated(implied) in documentation somewhere?

Comment: @ironic: The fact that it *does* happen is an implementation detail. The fact that it *can* happen is in the spec. (It says that the same delegate can be reused, anyway.)